# How I can set background to 50% of the web?

Tags: html, css

I want to set background to be in 50% of the page (width) and 100% height, but I recieve  half the picture and not the whole picture.

I want to get the whole picture but that the picture will display in half of the screen. Any suggestions how to do it?
CSS:

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
#background {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/mountain_lake_landscape_trees_79396_2560x1600.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/5yxbtyp9/

Comment: Please post the code used. `background-size: 50% 100%` should work, but I cannot see how you are doing this at the time. You need to set `html,body` both to `height: 100%` as well - and I can't know whether you did that. Post your code.

Comment: Thats doesnt work. I want that all the image will display, but just in half of the screen @somethinghere

Comment: Without code I cannot know what you tried or are trying to accomplish. What is 'just in half the screen'? Half a full image or a full image, halved?

Comment: I added a jsfiddle. as you can see, the background is half of the screen, but the image is cut by half too. I want that to display the whole image @somethinghere

Answer (score 3):

Just use `contain` instead of `cover` and it will do what it says on the tin. Also, I added `background-repeat` so you do not get a repeat. You can center the image by using `background-position: 50% 50%;`.

`cover` will try to stretch the image to fill the *entire* space **proportionally**. `contain` will fit the image in the space *available* **proportionally**. Any other sizes can be defined by you - you could use `100% auto` to always fill the width 100% proportionally, etc..

Have a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
#background {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/mountain_lake_landscape_trees_79396_2560x1600.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
```

### Update

To fill your entire half of the screen, just use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Why you would want to do that, I do not know, as it will not scale your image proportionally.

Comment: Thanks, but now the height is not 100%

Comment: I want that the image will be in full height but half of the width.

Comment: Yeah well I updated. God knows why you would want to that as it will break your images proportions. If you now say that its unproportional, then there is no answer available for you. **You cannot display _the whole image_ and retain proportions _and_ fill an entire randomly sized section**

Answer (score 1):

I've split your page in two sections, where `#background` is a viewport filling element that is positioned behind the content of the page. So now the background-image is not presented as a background image in your CSS, but brought to life with `<img>` tag in your HTML.

**See the fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/5yxbtyp9/3/

It is important to use relative positioning and `z-index` property to make this work. Otherwise it should fit your needs, if I understood the question correctly.

**EDIT:** If you want to keep the full height, you should change `#background .bg-image img`'s width setting to `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image in a parent container with a fixed `height/width`.

Your markup could be like

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
    
.chilgImg {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000"class="childImg" />
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5yxbtyp9/2/

Comment: First of, `img` tag self-close, so it is `<img />`, not `<img></img>`. Second, your `overflow` will probably have to be hidden as otherwise this makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry bout the image tag, did forget that. Sometimes it's a bad habit to only use your IDE's autocomplete.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle. as you can see, the background is half of the screen, but the image is cut by half too. I want that to display the whole image

Comment: Here is an updated Fiddle of yours, with a fixed width/height of your parent element.

https://jsfiddle.net/5yxbtyp9/2/

Answer (score 0):

Set your image width to 50% in your style tag or your external css file.

```
.image-class{ width: 50%;}
```